# HP Procurve 2010-24 J9019B 24 port network switch firmware

Tags: switch, firmware, hp

I have looked everywhere, and cannot find a firmware download for my network switch, HPE doesn't have the files as they are legacy and no longer accessible, if ANYONE has a copy of the latest firmware, PLEASE TELL ME!

Comment: Is the switch not working?   Devices like this only need firmware updates to correct problems.

Comment: It is working, and I can telnet into it, I need the firmware as from old articles online, I'm told that to fix a problem that blocks me from accessing the web interface, due to a old java version, I need to update the firmware

Comment: Try [this link](https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/Downloads/ProductsList.aspx?lang=en&cc=us&prodSeriesId=3356807). I couldn't test as it requires a login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to fix a problem that blocks me from accessing the web interface, due to a old java version, I need to update the firmware

As far as I know, there is no update available for that – even with the latest firmware that was available for this switch [series](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c02620067), the web UI [was still Java-based](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icK6M.png).

You're really not missing much though; the web UI of those switches had only minimal functionality exposed and it's often *easier* to do most things via Telnet instead.

```
ProCurve# conf
ProCurve(config)# vlan 5 untagged 1-8
ProCurve(config)# vlan 5 tagged 21-24
ProCurve(config)# [Ctrl-Z]
ProCurve# wr mem
```

All firmwares used to be published at ftp.hp.com and it's possible that they can be be found [on Archive.org](https://archive.org/search?query=%22ftp.hp.com%22) within one of the FTP grabs.