# Java error with the HP ProCurve 2510-24 J9019B network switch web interface

Tags: java, firmware, hp, legacy

I have a HP network switch i just bought, and tried to access the web interface, and got told this: This product requires the Java language, which is either disabled or not available on this browser.

> To use this product you must either upgrade your browser to one that
> is Java compliant, or enable the Java language on your current
> browser.

is there any way to get into the web interface, also, i currently dont have a copy of the latest firmware, so i cant update it, and the security tab in the java control panel wont work. and i already tried a guide to activate java in my browser, it didn't work

Comment: And the browser you use is?

Comment: Opera, but I tried chrome, edge, and Firefox

Comment: Do you have installed java on your computer? If yes follow these steps: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.html

Comment: Already tried that

Comment: Try with java version 8. Some software require old version.

Comment: https://github.com/rvojcik/firefox-icedtea might help. Haven't tested it myself though and no idea if it works in Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers no longer support the plugin type that was used to embed Java and similar. In other words, it's no longer just an option that you need to activate – the necessary code is literally *no longer there.*

Get VirtualBox (or some other virtualization app) and install Windows XP or Windows 2000 to a VM, then install an appropriately old version of Java JRE. (For WinXP any Java 6 or Java 8 should work. If you chose Win2000, install JRE [6u21](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-java-archive-javase6-downloads.html) as even 6u45 is too new for the OS.)

The answer from the [previous thread](https://superuser.com/a/1787829/1686) still applies.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an NPAPI plugin that the website tried to install, that has been abandoned a while ago. It's a very outdated technology. For example, Chrome [dropped support around 2015](https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation/) in version 42. There's no point of trying to "fix" it in modern browsers.

You should ask whoever told you to get around it if they're aware of that fact. Unless it's a very important product for your company, looking for a workaround is waste of time. They really should provide clear instructions of using older browsers/browser versions in that case, as it may not even support all the NPAPI versions.

Comment: The message OP quoted is what the switch itself shows when accessing its web UI.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was some quote from a manager/whoever to continue the thought, but makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to work with J2SE Runtime Environment 5.0 update 5 from old versions
[Old Java version](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/java-platform-runtime-5-0-update-5)
and it's worked with me.
but you also need to add the switch IP as a trusted website on IE.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).